How to reset select menu to placeholder in discord.js?
I am creating a system ticket and using dropdown as the ticket category selection option. I want when selecting it will automatically return to the placeholder like the gif I attached
The Example
    const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
      new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId("ticket_category_select")
        .setPlaceholder("Choose ticket category")
        .addOptions([
          {
            label: "Basic",
            value: "basic",
          },
          {
            label: "Premium",
            value: "premium",
          },
          {
            label: "Custom",
            value: "custom",
          },
        ])
    );

ChatGPT Not helping:(

You can do this by editing the message after sending it.

// Your codes...

    await interaction.reply({ components: [row] })

    const msg = await interaction.fetchReply();

    const newRow = new ActionRowBuilder();

    msg.components[0].components.forEach((component) => {
      if (component.customId == select.data.custom_id)
        newRow.addComponents(
          new StringSelectMenuBuilder({
            options: component.data.options,
            custom_id: component.customId,
            placeholder: "new placeholder",
          })
        );
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      msg.edit({
        components: [newRow],
      });
    }, 3000);

In this example, we first retrieve the message data (with fetchReply). Then we return on the components in the first actionRow of the message data we receive and detect the menu that is the same as our selection menu with custom_id. We leave the custom_id and options values the same and update the placeholder value as we want.
